# Use scanf to get a string and then use an if statement with that string, instead of characters in c language

Tags: c, string, if-statement, scanf

I know you can use scanf and get a character to use in an if clause, however, is there a way to do this with a string?

e.g.

```
printf("enter 'foo' to do 'bar', otherwise enter 'hay' to do 'wire');
scanf("%string", &stringNAME); //this is the part where I have no idea what to do

if (stringNAME == 'foo'){do bar} //here, issues occur with multicharacter character :/
if (stringNAME == 'hay'){do wire}
```

Comment: `if (strcmp(stringNAME, "foo") == 0) { do bar}`. Note the double quotes.

Comment: ahh so strcmp is like the getstring() equivalent from java?

--By the way, how do you define it as a string?

Comment: No, more like `compareTo()` for strings. It compares strings.

Comment: I see! thank you for the prompt input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost got it, just a few tweaks.

```
char stringNAME[10];
printf("enter 'foo' to do 'bar', otherwise enter 'hay' to do 'wire');
scanf("%9s", stringNAME); 

if (!strcmp(stringNAME,"foo"){do bar}
if (!strcmp(stringNAME,"hay")){do wire}
```

Note the number in the scanf, the 9. That should be one less (Or smaller) than the size of your input string. Otherwise you risk a buffer overflow, which is nasty business. `fgets` is a better choice, because you are forced to limit the number of characters. This is how you would do that (Just replace the `scanf` line)

```
fgets(stringNAME, 10, stdin)
```

Comment: Thank you, how do I initialize the string stringNAME? -- seeing as string is not a valid datatype in c to declare in main...?

Comment: You can (and should) use `scanf("%3s", &stringName)` to limit the number of characters read and avoid buffer overflow.

Comment: You don't need to initialize it, that is taken care in the reading of the name.

Comment: `scanf` is perfectly safe if you specify the size.  Of course, using a buffer of just 4 characters risks truncation -- if the user enters `foobar` it will match `foo` with this size 4 buffer, regardless of whether you use `scanf` of `fgets`

Comment: True enough. Will change my answer accordingly.

Comment: The other difference between `scanf` and `fgets` for this sort of thing is that `scanf` will read whitespace-delimited strings (so ignores excess whitespace) while `fgets` reads up to newlines, including any whitespace in what it returns.  If you want to ignore the whitespace, `fgets` needs a bunch of extra work.  In particular, if you replace the `scanf` with `fgets` in your code above, it will never match -- you need to change the strcmps to match against `"foo\n"` and `"hay\n"`

Comment: I just implemented it and it works, however I get two warnings:
1. "Format specifies type char * but the argument has type char (*)[10]" -- probably because of char stringNAME[10]
2. "Implicitly declaring library function 'strcmp' with type *int (const char *, const char *)"

Comment: I find the use of `if (!strcmp(s1, s2))` to be a bit obfuscated. `strcmp()` returns a value <0, 0, or >0 depending on the relationship between its arguments. For equality, I find it clearer to write `if (strcmp(s1, s2) == 0))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scanf with the %s specifier to read strings, but be sure you are reading into a string (eg: char array, dynamically allocated char*, etc...).  I can't see the rest of your code, but from the snippet you provide, I'm a bit suspicious of what &stringName is.

Here is an example of using scanf:

```
char s[100];
scanf("%s", s);
```

Now, having said that, please beware of using scanf to read strings.  The example above for instance, will only return the first word if you type in a multi-word string.

If you know you need scanf fine; otherwise, when in doubt, use fgets.

Comment: depends on what kind of strings you want.  `scanf` reads whitespace-delimited strings.  `fgets` reads newline-delimited strings.  You should specify the buffer size with both to avoid overflows.

Comment: `scanf("%s", s)` is as dangerous as `gets()`. It doesn't limit the number of characters it will try to store in the target buffer.

Answer (score 0):

A string is a vector of char, comparing (str1 == str2) will return if they are in the same memory address.

```
if(strcmp(stringName, "foo") == 0){
//stringName is Foo
}
```

this will work

Comment: Don't confuse the word "vector" with the C++ type of the same name. A string is, by definition, "a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null
character."